# ssh communication ports and iptables forwarding

Tags: ssh, iptables

I want to make possible communication from a client computer C1 to server S via router R. On my R i have set ip forwarding and with iptables I want to restrict communications only for ssh (and say web server, but now it's not important). What I don't know if sending and receiving of messages originate at port 22 and directed to port 22, or sending and receiving ports ar different.

Let's say may iptables are:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.1.1.1 -d 10.9.9.1 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.9.9.1 -d 10.1.1.1 ??? -m state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
```

So what I have to specify for the second rule and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the SSH server listens on TCP port 22. The port used on the client side is generally not static, predictable, or even configurable. I suggest matching on the server's source port in your second rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.9.9.1 -d 10.1.1.1 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: So you mean that ssh-server source port is also 22, like destination port (or maybe I'm confused about all this port stuff) ?

Comment: The server is using port 22. From the client's perspective, that's the destination port, but from the server's perspective, it's the source port.